# Can I reference a later table in a join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have some code that looks like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM invoices
LEFT JOIN shipments ON (
    shipments.id = invoices.shipment_id
)
LEFT JOIN details ON (
    details.id = invoices.detail_id
)
```

Basically, I want to look up the shipments table and the details table by an identifier from the invoices table. However, I would also like to join these two tables using something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM shipments
JOIN details ON (shipments.order = details.order)
```

Basically, I want a way of pulling **both** tables if either one of (invoices.shipment_id, invoices.detail_id) is found. However, I cannot reference a later table in a join, so I can't just do something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM invoices
LEFT JOIN shipments ON (
    shipments.id = invoices.shipment_id
    OR shipments.order = details.order
)
LEFT JOIN details ON (
    details.id = invoices.detail_id
)
```

Is there a way to do this while pulling both tables?

### Edit for clarity:

Here is a sample table structure

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    shipment_id integer,
    detail_id integer,
    data text
)

CREATE TABLE shipments (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    data text
)

CREATE TABLE details (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    shipment_id REFERENCES shipments (id),
    data text
)
```

`invoices.shipment_id` may or may not contain a `shipments.id`, and `invoices.detail_id` may or may not contain a `details.id`.

If `invoices.shipment_id` contains a valid id, I need to do something like:

```
SELECT
    shipments.data as shipment_data,
    details.data as detail_data,
FROM invoices
JOIN shipments ON (invoices.shipment_id = shipments.id)
JOIN details ON (details.shipment_id = shipments.id)
```

If `invoices.detail_id` contains a valid id, I need to do:

```
SELECT
    shipments.data as shipment_data,
    details.data as detail_data,
FROM invoices
JOIN details ON (invoices.detail_id = details.id)
JOIN shipments ON (details.shipment_id = shipments.id)
```

Is there some way of combining these two together cleanly?

Comment: Does `invoices` table have an `order` column as well?

Comment: The "order" join makes no sense (the name is badly chosen, too). If `shipments.id` and `details.id` are primary keys for the two _leaf_ tables, joining them based on another column could only introduce false hits (unrelated to the PKs). Please add a snippet of your data model to the question. BTW: the join ON `shipments.order = details.order` would also cause the left joins to behave as plain joins.

Comment: Agreed that the names are not chosen too well. Basically, I have an `id` field (order number) that is the actual primary key of the shipments table, and a corresponding `shipment_id` field in the details table. In my invoices table, I may or may not be provided the `shipment_id` or the `detail_id` field. Whichever one I get, I need to join back to the other table by that key.

Comment: How could you have shipped something that doesn't have at least 1 details record? Seems like a major design flaw to me.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand that text. Why don't you just provide us the relevant DDLs?

Comment: I can't ship something with no details - it's just that when an invoice comes through, sometimes I will be provided the number of the entire shipment, while sometimes I will be provided the number of a single detail within that shipment.

Comment: Please stop talking text. What is this `OR shipments.order = details.order` ? are it foreign keys to some hidden `orders` table (the name should have been `order_id`, in that case) It is impossible to anser this question without the datamodel; including semantics. I am confident that the SQL you need is _really_ trivial once the semantics come to the surface. (SQL with three tables is always trivial, IMnsHO)

Comment: I've added some DDLs and a better explanation. Hopefully this makes it clear what I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select * from invoices
left join (
  select shipments.id as ids, details.id as idd, * from shipments
  outer join details on (
   shipments.order=details.order
  )
) as sd on (
 sd.ids=invoices.shipment_id OR
 sd.idd = invoices.detail_id
)
```

Comment: It can be done without subselect if you `outer join` first and then `right join` `invoices`.

Comment: I see. So basically, create the joined shipments-details table right away, then join to it from invoices. Cool :)

Comment: The problem I am having is that if I do a subselect, my query does not hit the indexes on those two tables. If I do a right join, I have to join the whole set of shipments + details tables, which takes quite a bit of time.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i thought the question is about SQL server so please excuse me if my syntax is wrong. But i am quite sure the query will work in postgres.

this will look odd .. but if i understood right then following will do the job

```
SELECT *
FROM shipments INNER JOIN
details ON shipments.order = details.order RIGHT JOIN
invoices ON details.id = invoices.detail_id 
AND shipments.id = invoices.shipment_id
```

Comment: You need `OUTER JOIN` `shipments` and `details` and change `AND` in `details.id = invoices.detail_id AND shipments.id = invoices.shipment_id` to `OR`. Also - the question is about Postgres so no brackets `[]`

Comment: sorry for brackets i thought it was for SQL Server so sorry again for my syntax

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want. Perhaps this:

```
SELECT *
FROM invoices
  LEFT JOIN shipments ON
    shipments.id = invoices.shipment_id
  LEFT JOIN details ON
    details.id = invoices.detail_id
WHERE ( shipments.order = details.order
     OR shipments.order IS NULL
     OR details.order IS NULL
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Best I could come up with is this solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        shipments.data as shipment_data,
        details.data as detail_data,
    FROM invoices
    JOIN shipments ON (invoices.shipment_id = shipments.id)
    JOIN details ON (details.shipment_id = shipments.id)

    UNION

    SELECT
        shipments.data as shipment_data,
        details.data as detail_data,
    FROM invoices
    JOIN details ON (invoices.detail_id = details.id)
    JOIN shipments ON (details.shipment_id = shipments.id)
)
```

This isn't the prettiest solution, but it properly uses the indices on all three tables and returns both sets of records when needed.

Comment: Other than you should not use select * in production code (at least in the derived table containing the union), this looks like a good solution.

Comment: Just saw that you already posted a similar solution. `UNION` and `DISTINCT` would to the same here. The outer query is just noise. If your description is accurate, you don't even need `UNION`. Use `UNION ALL` instead ...

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`UNION ALL`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION):

**Assuming** that only one of `(invoices.shipment_id, invoices.detail_id)` can contain a value and the other one must be NULL and you are actually enforcing this rule with a `CHECK` constraint - because anything else would lead to ambiguity.

```
SELECT s.data AS shipment_data, d.data AS detail_data
FROM   invoices  i
JOIN   shipments s ON s.id = i.shipment_id
JOIN   details   d ON d.shipment_id = s.id

UNION ALL
SELECT s.data, d.data
FROM   invoices  i
JOIN   details   d ON d.id = i.detail_id
JOIN   shipments s ON s.id = d.shipment_id
```

- The 1st branch only returns values if `invoices.shipment_id IS NOT NULL`.
- The 2nd branch only returns values if `invoices.detail_id IS NOT NULL`.

Voilá.

I have a tingling sensation that your db schema leaves room for improvement. :)